# Cache Simulator WriteBack vs WriteThrough and WriteAllocate vs WriteNoAllocate

Tags: caching

I'm implementing a cache simulator where the user can specify write_allocate or write_no_allocate, write_back or write_through, as well as other variables like associativity and block size. Rather than keep track of "memory" we just keep track of a the number of data/instruction accesses, misses, and replacements.

For simpler test cases I'm getting the correct results but this changes for larger trace files. The common mistake is that I'm commonly registering too few misses and replacements (by the same number), so apparently some times when it should be a miss+replacement it interprets it as a hit. I was hoping someone could check my logic in regards to write_back vs write_through and write_allocate vs write_no_allocate. My init, search, insert, and delete methods are definitely correct (I'm sure of this) but it's my performAccess method that's killing me. Here's my pseudo_code for instruction_loads, where LRU_head is an array of cache_line "heads" for every set in the cache, where you can specify the set you care about with index.

```
If(INSTRUCTION_LOAD){

inst_accesess++;
if(LRU_head[index] == NULL) //miss no replacement
    inst_misses++;
    constructed = makeLine(tag);
    //insert constructed into set with correct index

    else if (search == false){ //miss, maybe replacement
    inst_misses++;
    constructedLine = makeLine(tag);
    if(room_in_set(index) == true){
    //insert constructed into set with correct index
    }
    else{ //LRU line will be evicted to make room
    inst_replacements++;
    //delete an entry based on Least Recently Used
    //insert constructed into that now vacated spot
    }

    else{ //hit
    //delete and insert it to make it most recently used element for LRU purposes
    }
}
```

What I want to clarify is whether write_alloc vs write_no_allocate should only affect misses/replacements for a data_store command, and write_back vs write_through should only affect words copied back to memory when a cache is being flushed or when a line is being evicted to make room? I'm getting the correct number of accesses for both data and instruction commands but it's the misses/replacements that are killing although I thought those should be very straightforward.